# How to transfer hosting of a HTTPS website to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a domain on Godaddy https://touchbasic.app
It was hosted on HostGator where everything worked and was easy to set up.
I can't figure out how to make my EC2 server host it so I can get rid of HostGator.
I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in when I go to my domain in my browser.

I'm hosting non-https domains just fine on my EC2 server. The problems is ".app" domains require https, and on EC2 that is super super complicated to set up hosting for. I've spent days on this. I've posted in the ec2 forums but it seems that people rarely get responses there.

Do I have to use a load balancer? I don't want one. Does it do anything if I only have 1 server?
Which tutorial should I follow? I've tried all of them already and restarted several times.

I've added to httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin feedback@touchbasic.app
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/touchbasicdotapp"
ServerName touchbasic.app
ErrorLog "logs/touchbasic.app-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/touchbasic.app-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and did httpd restart.

I added rules to my security group:

```
HTTPS
TCP
443
0.0.0.0/0

HTTPS
TCP
443
::/0
```

I created the folder with index.html in it /var/www/html/touchbasicdotapp

I've created a Hosted Zone in Route 53, which gave me 4 nameservers, which I set in Godaddy.

I created an A record with the IP of my server. That did not work so I made a Load Balancer. I made a certificate for my domain and added a CNAME with that in it. I added a SOA record with my load balancer in it. It has a listener with ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08 and SSL Certificate. Now the error is 502 Bad Gateway. When I go to load balancer targets, it says status unhealthy (health checks failed). I can't find any relevant log files. Do I need to set up S3 just to have log files?

Is there anyone I can pay to set this up for me? If I upgrade my account will Amazon set this up for me? Do I need a very deep knowledge of servers to host a very simple .app website on amazon?

Comment: you have to create a certificate from AWS ACM, integrate it with LB and point DNS entry to LB. you do not have to manage any thing at instance level. SSL terminate at instance in case of LB

Comment: A lot of description but what exactly is happening right now?  I mean is your domain resolved properly to your load balance or instance ? @Adiii is right, if you are using ALB with certificate then SSL will terminate on Load balance, you will hit your server on http

Comment: What's happening now is as I said, my website does not load in a browser, instead it times out. How do I check if my domain is resolved properly to my load balance or instance?

Comment: As I said, I already created a certificate and it is set as a listener in my load balancer.

Comment: did your LB security group allow 443 or 80 for the public? is the target group is healhty for LB? if healthy the issue with LB if not healhty then issue with EC2.

Comment: Okay I just switched my LB to use my same security group that allows 443 and 80 for public. Now there is a different error in the browser: 502 bad gateway.

Comment: so it is for sure you backend is not running. either the application is not running or either the SG not allowing. check health of target

Comment: might be the case backend listening on different port? pls do mentioned me in comment so I got notification otherwise I have to refresh page :(

Comment: @Adiii It says: Healthy? No (Availability Zone contains no healthy targets) Status: unhealthy (Health checks failed)

Comment: so something wrong with EC2, the application is not running check the logs. or check the security group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199552/discussion-between-adiii-and-curtis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to manage SSL at the instance level as LB do that for you. So better to go with this approach.

- Create a certificate from AWS ACM
- Integrate it with LB and point DNS entry to LB
- you do not have to manage any thing at instance level. SSL terminates
  and send a decrypted request to the target.
- Target group will receive http traffic.

Update apache config to listen of port `80` and do restart.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin feedback@touchbasic.app
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/touchbasicdotapp"
ServerName touchbasic.app
ErrorLog "logs/touchbasic.app-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/touchbasic.app-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```